# SSRS Issue with values that are text and number exporting into excel

Tags: excel, reporting-services

I am having an issue where I have similar hyphenated values 1304-4(text) and 1306 (number) The main issue I am trying to overcome, is when I export my SSRS report (.rdl) to excel, I get an error in excel, where it shows numbers are formatted as text.  I seek to avoid this, and am open to any solutions to do so.  I have searched vigorously and not found a solution that works.  I have noticed that I can multiply the numerical values 1306*1.0000 and that would fix the issue, if not for the text values 1304-4*1.000 = null in report.  Is there any way to accomplish this? I can cast my dataset as any other type of values, however SSRS only wants one kind of value in a field, as far as I am aware.  Any thoughts or help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you post some example data as text?

Comment: Excel will mot treat numbers as text as long as you don't make them text in the report. Your "numbers" seem to come from a text-column in the report, so you cant expect Excel to treat some of the values differently.

Comment: The data below was copied from the Excel that SSRS produced.  The values are set as VARCHAR on the table I am pulling them from.  I believe SSRS formats everything to text based on a field only being able to have one data type.             
     ITEM
     1004-2
     1005-3
     1005-4
     1010000
     1010015
     1010060

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this expression

```
 =IIF(IsNumeric(Fields!<Your Field Name>.Value),Val(Fields!<Your Field Name>.Value),cstr(Fields!<Your Field Name>.Value))
```

Comment: This was exactly what I was needed.  This fixed my issue 100 %.  A great many thanks and I hope you have an awesome weekend.  Can you recommend any resources where one would be able to similar knowledge?

Comment: @Thomas Glad to know that it has solved your issue. MSDN is always a great source of information. You can visit my BLOG : http://www.bi-rootdata.com/search/label/SSRS and could found some interesting posts.

Comment: Thank you very much! I am looking forward to checking it out and continuing to learn.  I really appreciate you being such an awesome member of the community.  I can't wait until I can start helping people.